# php echo not working in ternary operator, example: $test == 'a test' ? echo 'test is not empty' : '';

Tags: php

I have this ternary operation:

```
$test == 'a test' ? echo 'test is not empty' : '';
```

I'm wondering why the echo won't work?

This is a php code.

Comment: What is `$test` set to? If it's not `'a test'`, then the `echo` branch *shouldn't* execute.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because this is invalid syntax. If necessary add this at the top of your script and PHP will tell you so:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**Update:** Wait, adding this shouldn't be necessary since it's a parser error, so the script won't get there anyway. Instead if necessary set `display_errors` to `On` in your `php.ini` and restart your server. **/Update**

It should be written like this:

```
echo $test == 'a test' ? 'test is not empty' : '';
```

or better this since echoing nothing doesn't make much sense:

```
if($test == 'a test') echo 'test is not empty';
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is a statement (well, PHP calls it a "language construct"). Statements cannot be used inside of expressions; that's what differentiates a statement from an expression.